# No events in leverice jira events channel

Tags: message

I created a Leverice Jira channel but there are no events appearing in the events subchannel. I believe I filled in all the fields in the channel creation dialogue correctly. Any ideas about what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created some walkthrough videos to show proper setup of the Jira integration in Leverice. Please double check that you followed the steps outlined in these two clips:

Initial Jira integration setup video: https://drive.google.com/a/leverice.com/file/d/1cEje0eb31z3JihaL29TUE_hbg_KXvfaN/view?usp=sharing

Setting up icons/commands in Jira integration: https://drive.google.com/a/leverice.com/file/d/1b5R6oXaZM_i20p0h_VvHJhuhbscXhqcK/view?usp=sharing